# React Native with semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, semantic-ui-react

I want to use the same component lib on web and mobile with react. I know that [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) fits to web, but tried to use it in a react-native project without success.
Am I missing some specific config, or it does not work in both platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this package meet your need in react-native

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@muratoner/semantic-ui-react-native

Comment: I'd love to use this package so thanks so much for building this! But I just hope that ALL components available in the Semantic UI React (web) would be made available for native in this package to its full capability. Ty!

Answer (score 4):

You're not missing any configuration. Semantic UI React only generates elements using `react-dom`. The only way to use it with React Native would be if the entire library was updated to render native elements for other target environments. [This is not something that Semantic UI supports](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/790)... and would represent a significant, likely breaking, refactor to do.